# Maven resource filtering not working

Tags: maven

Here my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.agipi</groupId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>


    <artifactId>com.agipi.layouts</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>



    <properties>
        <project.test>1.2.3</project.test>
        </properties>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0-m2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pluginType>layouttpl</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And one of my file "liferay-plugin-package.properties" in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF :

```
Bundle-Version=${project.test}
```

When i do a mvn clean install the value is not replaced. Any idea?

Edit : Actually in target/ i got a .war in which value is NOT replaced, and I got some folders as well.

One of them is the "class" folder in which I got the file "liferay-plugin-package.properties" in which value IS replaced.

I need value to be replaced in the .war

Comment: What kind of file would you like to filer? Please show the whole pom file and the structure of your project...

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: In this case I recommend to use something like maven-bundle-plugin from the Apache Felix project or bndTools....make this easier than handling this with filtering etc. Furthermore I don't understand why a war needs a MANIFEST.MF with contains a bundle version? Only for bundles which will be used as dependencies this is needed...

Comment: I tried but nothing happen, the MANIFEST.MF in the war does not contains Bundle-Version key

Answer (score 2):

I think filtering works correctly but a later stage running plugin overwrites your filtered files.
Try running `mvn clean compile` instead of package to verify if this is the case.

Comment: When i do a mvn clean compile I got only the classes folder in which value is replaced. But i still don"t have any idea to get the value replaced in the .war :/

Comment: I tried to remove every other plugin but still the same, value is not replaced

Comment: A bit confusing; The location you show in your question is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`; this is different than the `classes` folder you mention. 
If you try to run `mvn prepare-package` you could have a look at the `target` folder and see if those values are filtered or not (before war plugin).